# Webpack Not Running (No Errors)

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

My config used to work on my Macbook Pro 2017 but I recently got a new MBP.

When I run `webpack` or `webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js` in terminal, nothing is happening. I don't get any errors and there's no progress. It just freezes here:

[image]

I've installed webpack, webpack-merge, webpack-cli, and webpack-dev-server globally. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled all 4 packages (as dev dependencies). I've tried adding the `webpack` and `webpack serve` commands as npm scripts. I've also tried adding a `port: 8080` and `allowedHosts: 'all'` setting to my `devServer` config.

Any suggestions?

Here's my `webpack.dev.js`

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: { hot: true }
});
```

My `webpack.common.js` configuration:

```
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var env = dotenv.config({ path: './.env' }).parsed,
    envDef = {};

for (var key in env){ envDef[key] = JSON.stringify(env[key]); }

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/i,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            { test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: { filename: 'images/[name][ext]' }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: { filename: 'fonts/[name][ext]' }
            },
            { test: /\.(csv|tsv)$/i, use: ['csv-loader'] },
            { test: /\.xml$/i, use: ['xml-loader'] }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envDef),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.html') })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Then it's time to start removing code by running through the [mcve] exercise, until webpack no longer "gets stuck". And then whatever you removed last is part of the problem to look into.